# How do you publish a nuget package when it has dependencies on non nuget assemblies

Tags: c#, nuget

Struggling to find any information online for this but I am in a scenario where I have a class library project that has dependencies on plenty of nuget packages, but also requires a local assembly which is not on nuget.

So for example godot creates a project for you which bungs in the dlls into a local folder for your project to reference and just adds `Reference` with hints to your csproj, now I need to depend on those assemblies for the library to work, but the consumers of this package would have to have those assemblies available locally.

So is there a way for nuget to be told that an assembly is needed but it isnt provided via nuget?

Comment: Are you exclusively looking for "technical" ways, or will an answer like "highlight it really clearly in the documentation" suffice?

Comment: Technical solution ideally, i.e does Nuget provide some convention/packaging config for these scenarios, or can you only publish to nuget if everything it depends on is in nuget etc? (In reality I can work around this by just zipping up everything and providing that as the release, but would be nicer if I could nuget it)